# Use of preg_match with glob() under conditions

Tags: php

I Currently test all results that i have found in Google, but im not that so lucky to get it all.
I wanted to have a function that will search a wildcard name of the file like: **filename.patch.php** inside my folder. And if the filename does not exist, throw the page to 404. However, im not really sure if i am doing it right. Here's the code.

```
$results = glob("{manager/patches/$templateHandler/*.patch.php}", GLOB_BRACE);
if(preg_match_all($results, $pageHandler)) {
  include 'manager/patches/'.$templateHandler.'/'.$pageHandler.'.patch.php';
} else {
  include '404.php';
}
```

Although i understand that there is an array output here, but that was my problem. I don't know how to extract the output to my preg_match.

Note: Im not a programmer, so bear with me.

==

Found Solution (so far)!

```
$folder = glob("manager/patches/$templateHandler/*.patch.php");
$dir = implode(" ", $folder);

if(preg_match("/\b$pageHandler\b/i", $dir)) {
  include 'manager/patches/'.$templateHandler.'/'.$pageHandler.'.patch.php';
} else {
  include '404.php';
}
```

Ok, Im happy that this one answer my question, however, i would like to consult, if this is standard and safe to use? Because the output that i am looking is displaying correct.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues here.

1)  the glob function returns an array, not a string.  So you need to loop through the array and test all the returned file names against the regular expression.

2) preg_match_all finds multiple instances of the same regular expression within a single string, which is probably not what you want.  preg_match is probably what you want.

3) preg_match and preg_match all will return an array, if you specify that it should, by providing the array name as the third parameter.  It doesn't actually return it... it's just available in scope.

```
preg_match($regex, $string, $matches)
```

$matches is now available in scope.

Each element of $matches contains different things, but you'll be interested in $matches[0], the first element, which will be the match that was found.  In other words, if $matches[0] == 'string_to_match', you have found the string you are looking for.  As well, you can just test for a return value of 1 (expression was found in string), or 0 (error, or expression not found in string).

On the whole, though, I'm not sure this is the best way to accomplish what you're looking for, particularly as glob() returns an array that could match (or not) multiple files when you test it.

Comment: Hi sir, thanks for the idea. I did another trial and found a solution (although im still not sure). The solution i found was displaying correctly my output.